# Linq insert with nullable datetime column

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I am trying to do an insert with Linq and keep getting the sqlDateTime overflow error.

I have a nullable DateTime field in the DB.

I am using linq to sql and my class for the dateTime is:

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_concern_DateTo", DbType="DateTime")]
public System.Nullable<System.DateTime> concern_DateTo {
    get { return this._concern_DateTo; }
    set {
        if ((this._concern_DateTo != value)) {
            this.Onconcern_DateToChanging(value);
            this.SendPropertyChanging();
            this._concern_DateTo = value;
            this.SendPropertyChanged("concern_DateTo");
            this.Onconcern_DateToChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

I have a JQuery datepicker that selects the date and I am checking that it is a dateTime:

```
DateTime PartC_DateTo = new DateTime();

//'Date To' Part C
//================
if (txt_PartC_DateTo.Text != string.Empty) {
    DateTime.TryParse(txt_PartC_DateTo.Text, out PartC_DateTo);
}
```

then when I am assigning I am using this code:

```
if (txt_PartC_DateTo.Text != string.Empty) {
    concern.concern_DateTo = PartC_DateTo;
}
```

Then when I `submitChanges()`, the SQLDateTime error appears as I'm writing the exceptions to the screen for testing.

Comment: This question can be answered easily be stepping through the code. Set a breakpoint on `concern.concern_DateTo = PartC_DateTo;` and see what you're setting it to.

Comment: How should I set it? new DateTime("yymmdd") something like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to declare a `DateTime?`

```
        DateTime? PartC_DateTo = null;
        DateTime dateOut = new DateTime();
        if (txt_PartC_DateTo.Text != string.Empty)
        {
            DateTime.TryParse(txt_PartC_DateTo.Text, out dateOut);
            PartC_DateTo = dateOut;
        }
```

This answer is meant to accept the `null` since your `concern_DateTo` is nullable.

Lets consider this scenario about your codes. You're declaring a `new DateTime()` and the given value is `1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM` and the MS SQL SERVER [could not accept that](http://jerrytech.blogspot.com/2005/03/earliest-date-held-by-sql-server.html).

Try this way:

```
        DateTime? PartA_Date;
        DateTime dateOut2;
        if (!DateTime.TryParse(txt_PartA_Date.Text, out dateOut2))
        {
            lbl_message.Text += " * 'Date' is not a valid date!<br/>"; txt_PartA_Date.BackColor =
                Color.FromName(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ErrorColour"]);
        }
        else
        {
            PartA_Date = dateOut2;
        }
```

**Hint**: The easiest way to develop a program, the Fields of the table from your database must be `nullable` not including the `Primary Key`. If you don't want to accept the `null` to your database just leave your program to manage.

```
 if (IsNull) return;
```

Comment: The out argument does not match the parameter type. That is the red squiggly

Comment: Still does the same. I have other datetimes but theye are not nullable.I am using them in the same way. is this wrong?

Comment: okay since we focus on the `concern_DateTo`, then you must try to set the others that accept the `null`.

Comment: I am declaring them as `DateTime PartA_Date = new DateTime();                    if (!DateTime.TryParse(txt_PartA_Date.Text, out PartA_Date))
                    {
                        lbl_message.Text += " * 'Date' is not a valid date!<br/>";
                        txt_PartA_Date.BackColor = Color.FromName(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ErrorColour"]);
                    }`

Comment: The Assign the concern_PartAdate to the PartA_Date. is this wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You don't check whether or not `DateTime.TryParse` was successful (by means of the return value), so `PartC_DateTo` could still well be an invalid (default) `DateTime` for the database.

Instead, keep your `DateTime` value as `null`, and...

```
DateTime parseableDate;
DateTime? someNullableDate;
if (DateTime.TryParse(txt_PartC_DateTo.Text, out parseableDate)) {
   someNullableDate = parseableDate;
}
```

You can use someNullableDate here and assume that it is either A) a valid date, or B) null; however, note that January 1, 0001 is a valid date and will parse but may not be accepted by your database engine, so check your lowest possible date value in your database, and further accommodate for such discrepancies.

Comment: @StudentRik I've updated with a solution, though I worry that our words alone can't be worked from.

Comment: I have other date fields and I am doing the same for them is this not right. Tey are not nullable. When I step through my program and check the values they are all good dates converted to DateTime

Answer (score 1):

`new DateTime();` is not null, it is `DateTime.MinValue` (January 1, 0001). This is a date before the sql `datetime` min value (January 1, 1753).

Either use `null` or use the sql type `datetime2`